# Change CA certificate name in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ssl

I'm creating certificate in Kubernetes for Vault (it does not really matter that this is for Vault). The signer is Kubernetes itself. Here are the steps I'm doing:

1. Generate private key `openssl genrsa -out ${TMPDIR}/vault.key 2048`
2. Then I create CSR:

> ```
> cat <<EOF >${TMPDIR}/csr.conf
> [req]
> req_extensions = v3_req
> distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
>
> [req_distinguished_name]
> countryName            = DE
> stateOrProvinceName    = Berlin
> organizationName       = OrgX
> organizationalUnitName = TeamX
> commonName             = ${SERVICE}.${NAMESPACE}.svc
>
> [v3_req]
> basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
> keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
> extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
> subjectAltName = @alt_names
>
> [alt_names]
> DNS.1 = ${SERVICE}
> DNS.2 = ${SERVICE}.${NAMESPACE}
> DNS.3 = ${SERVICE}.${NAMESPACE}.svc
> DNS.4 = ${SERVICE}.${NAMESPACE}.svc.cluster.local
> DNS.5 = ${SERVICE}-active.${NAMESPACE}.svc.cluster.local
> DNS.6 = vault-0.vault-internal
> DNS.9 = localhost
> IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
> EOF
> ```

3. I'm signing it with the private key:
   `openssl req -new -key ${TMPDIR}/vault.key -subj "/CN=${SERVICE}.${NAMESPACE}.svc" out ${TMPDIR}/server.csr -config ${TMPDIR}/csr.conf`
4. I'm creating CSR k8s object:

> ```
> cat <<EOF >${TMPDIR}/csr.yaml
> apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1
> kind: CertificateSigningRequest
> metadata:
>   name: ${CSR_NAME}
> spec:
>   groups:
>   - system:authenticated
>   request: $(cat ${TMPDIR}/server.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n')
>   signerName: beta.eks.amazonaws.com/app-serving
>   usages:
>   - digital signature
>   - key encipherment
>   - server auth
> EOF
> ```

5. I'm approving it: `kubectl certificate approve ${CSR_NAME}`
6. This part is important. To use this certificate I need to add CA cert to my `keyChain Access` (I'm using Mac). To retrieve it I'm using:

   `kubectl get secret -o jsonpath="{.items[?(@.type==\"kubernetes.io/service-account-token\")].data['ca\.crt']}" | base64 --decode > ${TMPDIR}/vault.ca 2>/dev/null || true`

Now, I'm doing this for few k8s clusters because I need few Vault certificates from the different clusters. Now, all of them are called `kubernetes`. When I'm adding the second one (from the second k8s cluster) the first is overwritten because it has the same name. How can this be changed? How can I control name of CA certificate so it won't be just called `kubernetes`. Can I customize the name?

Answer (score 0):

you can just rename the certificate name as long as you don#t change anything inside the certificate itself.  :)